# C++/CX XAML image visibility

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, c++-cx

I have a project in Visual Studio 2012, using XAML & C++/CX. 
I would like to set the Visibilty property of an image object in XAMl to "Collapsed" from the C++ code. Here's what I got...

```
<Image x:Name="card1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="237" Margin="246,138,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="178" Source="b2fv.png" Tapped="card1_Tapped"/>
```

and I'm trying to set it to Collapsed but can't find any examples of how to do it in C++/CX?

```
card1->SetValue(Visibility);
```

This is as far as i got. I imagine it's relatively simple, but i can't get the right syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set visibility like this:

```
card1->Visibility = Windows::UI::Xaml::Visibility::Collapsed;
card1->Visibility = Windows::UI::Xaml::Visibility::Visible;
```

Comment: I have a related question on how to set an "id" # for the image object and how to retrieve it in c++/cx... will post a new question and hope you can help me. thanks.